# Cómo puedo formatear el código de Oracle SQL en VS Code?

Tags: sql, oracle, vscode, plsql, vs

tengo un problema con el formato del código de Oracle SQL en VS Code. Resulta que no puedo formatear el código. Tengo instalado el plugin de oracle-format desde el marketplace y no sé por qué cuando le doy al format, me lanza este error:

**Command failed: "sql" /nolog @"c:\Users\user.vscode\extensions\mp.vscode-oracle-format-0.1.5\format.sql" Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal oracle.dbtools.raptor.scriptrunner.cmdline.SqlCli
Origen: oracle-format (extensión).**

He intentdado modificar el archivo settings.js y cuando entro no sé qué tocar.

En caso de que este plugin no funcionase, si me pudiérais recomendar uno o si no hiciese falta o alguna solución a esto os lo agradecería.

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Es difícil encontrar un plugin adecuado a la programación sql, te recomiendo revisar en la configuración del plugin, la ruta del sql client, quiero decirte también que las interfaces sql que ayudan a formular son la mayoría pagas, intenta ver ejemplos y buscar en logs de tu servidor, saludos

Comment: ¿y porqué no usa alguno de los clientes IDE que hablan directamente con la base de datos Oracle? Hay varios gratuitos: SQLTools, SQL Developer, etc.